# Play 2.2 google closure compiler opiton nonStandardJsDocs

Tags: playframework-2.2, google-closure-compiler

How to specify nonStandardJsDocs at Build.scala to turn off the warning of js compile warnings from google compiler?

I tried this

```
closureCompilerOptions += "nonStandardJsDocs=OFF"
```

or this

```
closureCompilerOptions ++= Seq("--jscomp_off", "nonStandardJsDocs"),
```

but it doesn't work.

Here is the error when I run play dist:

```
com.google.javascript.jscomp.LoggerErrorManager println
WARNING: /myfolder/modules/web-front/app/assets/js/vendor/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.js:374: WARNING - Parse error. illegal use of unknown JSDoc tag "ngdoc"; ignoring it
 * @ngdoc directive
   ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--extra_annotation_name` arg to suppress warnings for Angular annotations.
The following works (tried in compiler version v20140814):

```
--extra_annotation_name ngdoc --extra_annotation_name restrict
```